# Can't get delegate to use performsegue

Tags: objective-c, delegates, segue, multipeer-connectivity

I'm new to coding in general so please bear with me as I explain the issue. I am using Multipeer connectivity in my app that so far only consists of 1 nav controller and 1 chat interface.

I have used a seperate class to declare the MCSession,MCnearbyadvert & MCnearbybrowser. Within this class I was hoping to use a delegate when the certificate for connection is received to queue for peformseguewithidentifier into the chat interface. I have read up a lot of similiar questions and unfortunately none of the solutions have helped.

Here is my ViewController.h file

```
#import "MCManager.h"
#import "ChatViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MCManDelegate>


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBSDKLoginButton *faceBookButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *chatId;

-(void)onRequestSuccess;
@end
```

Here is the relevant parts of my ViewController.m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ChatViewController.h"
#import "MCManager.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController() <FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) AppDelegate *appDelegate;

@end

@implementation ViewController


 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:YES];
FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
loginButton.delegate = self;
loginButton.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:loginButton];
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]){
    [self createButton];
    MCManager *mcmanager = [[MCManager alloc] init]
    mcmanager.delegate = self;
    _appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]    delegate];
        [[_appDelegate mcManager] advertiseSelf];
    }
}
-(void)onRequestSuccess{
    NSLog(@"doSegue initiated");
    [self doSegue];
}

- (void)doSegue{
    NSLog(@"doSegue loaded");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ChatViewControl" sender:self];
}
```

Please bear in mind I have tried to place the [[MCManager alloc] init] in several different parts of the code but can't seem to find the right spot.

anyway here is my MCManager.h

```
@protocol MCManDelegate <NSObject>
@required
 -(void)onRequestSuccess;
@end

@interface MCManager : NSObject <MCSessionDelegate,MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate,MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate> {
    id<MCManDelegate> delegate;
}

   @property (weak) id<MCManDelegate>delegate;
+some other unrelated properties
```

here is my MCManager.m file and relevant method

```
 #import "MCManager.h"
 @implementation MCManager

 @synthesize delegate = _delegate;
- (void) session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveCertificate:(nullable    NSArray *)certificate fromPeer:(nonnull MCPeerID *)peerID certificateHandler:(nonnull void (^)(BOOL))certificateHandler
{
    NSLog(@"Handled Invitation");
    certificateHandler(YES);
    [self.delegate onRequestSuccess];
     NSLog(@"%@",self.delegate);


}
```

The NSLog handled invitation appears however the NSlog self.delegate produces (null) which i know is incorrect and I know its related to how i initialise the delegate in the viewcontroller.m file but I'm just not sure how to fix it! Would greatly appreciate help...

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

Declare  MCManager *mcmanager globally and initialize in viewDidLoad

Comment: I tried this before but had no luck I declared the variable using `@property (nonatomic, strong & weak) MCManager *mcmanager` as well as using `extern MCManager *mcmanager`. I'm still a little unfamiliar with variable types so feel free to correct me if I did something wrong.

Comment: also i'm initialisting like this   `MCManager *mcmanager = [[MCManager alloc] init];
    mcmanager.delegate = self;`

Comment: Have you tried by interchange these two line  certificateHandler(YES);
    [self.delegate onRequestSuccess];

Comment: yeah its not working since the self.delegate is coming up as '(null)' so its running the code but delegate isn't initialised correctly. I'm just not sure how to fix it

Comment: Hello, i tried with sample project at my side but this scenario working fine... and can't figure out why its happening at your side. There is a other option use internal notification for that.

Comment: how can internal notification help ? i was hoping to get devices to connect when they are close by ... I ran the initalising section through the debugger and it came up as 'nil' I've seen this error heaps on stack exchange but most of them are careless errors that i haven't made I'm really pretty confused....

Comment: // Step 1:  In your viewController vidDidload and add method notificationSelector:
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationSelector:) name:@"GIVE_ANY_NAME" object:nil];

Comment: // Step 2:  posting notification where you are calling delgate
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Key1",@"Value1",@"Key2",@"Value1", nil];
    NSNotification *internal = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"GIVE_ANY_NAME" object:nil userInfo:dict];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:internal];

Comment: // Step 3:  This will called
-(void)notificationSelector:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSDictionary *dict = notification.userInfo;
} I hope this will work out

Answer (score 0):

This question is still technically unanswered however I found a much better solution which was to use geofire along with my firebase. Hope this helps others who are trying to get users to connect to near by devices !